# CORS and jQuery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors

I'm not sure if it's simply a case of an incorrect setting in my ajax call or my misunderstanding how CORS works.

I have a web server running on my box in the network-- `larryq.mycompany.com`.  I have full access to that machine and have been setting the following headers on my pages:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin = *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers = 'Authorization'
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials = true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods = "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"
```

When I load my current testing page I see those values in my response headers.

On this page I'm making an ajax call to another server on the network, using OAuth:

```
var OAuthAuthorizationString = 'OAuth realm="http://www.mycompany.com/", oauth_consumer_key="consumerkey"....oauth_nonce="1446691", oauth_version="1.0"'

$.ajax
({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://secure.mycompany.com?val1=33&val2=45',
    data: [], 
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'OAuthAuthorizationString');
    }
})
.done(function (html) {
    $("#results").empty();
    $("#results").append(html);
})
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    $("#results").empty();
    $("#results").append(textStatus);
});
```

Right now when I run this I get a 403 Forbidden response during what appears to be the CORS preflight check.

If I open the Google Advanced Rest Client and craft the same GET request using that OAuth string in the Authorization header, the request works and I get back my data.

I must be doing something wrong, but can't figure what?  Am I running into some ajax restriction I'm not aware of or (quite likely) not setting things up correctly?

I'm using jQuery 1.10 fwiw.

Comment: Ignoring the Google client for a moment, you've set the access control headers up on one server, but you're making requests of a different server? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: 403 Forbidden = server-side issue.  Have you made the file w,r,r ?  (chmod 755)

Comment: @MikeW I hear what you're saying.  I thought the same thing until I got the Google client working, then said "Do I know CORS and its limitations?  Not really?  Then let's try this.." whereupon it's been 3 hours of head scratching and maybe-this-will-work

Comment: Same `GET` request? If you believe it is the preflight request then you would need to try `OPTIONS` instead of `GET`.

Comment: What code is your server written in? My guess is that your issue is similar to what is happening here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503822/403-error-with-post-call-to-a-nodejs-server-which-is-on-diffrent-localhost-url

e.g. the request is fine, but something else is blocking it. If that doesn't work, try comparing the request/response headers of your request with the Google Advanced Rest Client (What is the Google Advanced Rest Client?).

Comment: @monsur thanks for the tips.  We're using ASP.Net here.  The Google Advanced Rest Client is a chrome extension available at the  Chrome web store.  Sorry, I'm so used to it that I thought everyone knew what it was off the top of their heads...

Comment: @larryq Ok, in that case your best bet is to do a comparison between the request/response headers in order to determine what the differences are.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand how to use CORS myself, so this may not solve your problem, but according to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS):

> Important note: when responding to a credentialed request,  server must specify a domain, and cannot use wild carding.

So you cannot have:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin = *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials = true
```

Instead, you must explicitly specify the allowed origin. For example:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin = larryq.mycompany.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials = true
```